Not able to get OpenAI assistant's reply after handling thread.run.requires_action event in a run
I'm going to try formulating this high-level. I know it's not ideal, but bear with me. I'm sure if you recognize the problem, you're able to give me a clue:

Setup: I'm messing with the OpenAI Assistans API on NodeJS

Defined an assistant on the OpenAI Platform
Wrote a NodeJS client application to run it (stream-SDK-style)
Using Discord as a chat frontend (but that doesn't matter at all)
Basic chatting with the assistant is working fine so far!


Trying to get custom function calling to work:

Defined a function request body on the OpenAI Platform
Managed to catch the thread.run.requires_action event on the client

Handled my custom function call and successfully relayed outputs to client.beta.threads.runs.submitToolOutputsStream
Problem: Never received a textDone (or any other event for that matter) after that - the run seems to just end after a thread.run.requires_action - so I don't get the assistant's reply!
Observing the thread on the OpenAI Platform however clearly shows:

The assistant received the function response from my client
The assistant generated a message on that response


Question: What do I need to do after calling client.beta.threads.runs.submitToolOutputsStream in order to pick up the run again and retrieve the assistant's reply?





